# Como pegar nome do usuário na URL?

Tags: php

Estou criando um *site* e gostaria de fazer um sistema de *profiles* do tipo:
`meusite.com/NICKUSUARIO`.

E gostaria de saber como faço para pegar esse *nick* na URL e passar para o arquivo `profile.php` por exemplo.

Eu sei usar colocando `?nick=nickuser`, porém gostaria de fazer de um modo mais agradável para usuário digitar tendo que colocar somente `meusite.com/nickusuario`.

Answer (score 3):

Basta usar [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php) para *interpreta uma URL e retorna os seus componentes*, e posteriormente a função [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php) para remover a `/`

```
$parse = parse_url( 'http://www.meusite.com/NICKUSUARIO' );
echo trim( $parse['path'] , '/' );
```

O código acima retorna apenas `NICKUSUARIO`.

---

**Update**

A URL completa você consegue usando `'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Mas como eu pego esse valor da url que o usuario digito no browser, no seu exemplo você só quebrou uma string/url q vc já tem, no caso eu não sei oque o usuario digito no browser ainda.
E como eu redireciono para um arquivo php essa url ?

Comment: @Pertile o arquivo `profile.php` é um include ou um redirecionamento?

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que você esteja querendo criar *URL's* amigáveis, certo?
Para isso, você pode criar um arquivo `.htaccess` e configurá-lo de forma que o texto após a barra seja interpretado como um parâmetro `GET`, depois para recebê-lo no *PHP* você utiliza normalmente o `$_GET` (no caso `$_GET['nick']`), como se a url fosse de fato `?nick=nickuser`.

*Ficaria assim:*

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#Reescrita de URL
#Na linha abaixo será definido que o parâmetro nick poderá receber letras e números
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?nick=$1
```

Já no **arquivo PHP**, você receberia normal:

### PHP

```
<?php
echo $_GET['nick'];
?>
```

No caso da url acessada ser 'profile.php/testeNome' ou 'profile.php?nick=testeNome' o resultado será a exibição de:

```
testeNome
```

Comment: Vlw era isso mesmo :)
eu usei assim :
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA,N

Answer (score 1):

```
$parse = parse_url( 'http://www.meusite.com/NICKUSUARIO' );
$value = trim( $parse['path'] , '/' );
```

Sua url seria fixa e o usuário digitaria apenas o que vêm após a /,
ex: `http://www.meusite.com/stack`

sua variável $value teria o valor que precisa ai é só você usa-la como pretende,
ex: `<?php header("location:user.php?nick=".$value);?>`

Answer (score 0):

Para **simplificar**, acredito que fazendo assim, já resolve no caso:

```
 $value = trim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'],'/');
```

Há outras maneiras...

a) Usando **`parse_url()`**:

```
    $parse = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $value = trim( $parse['path'] , '/' );
```

b) Usando **`preg_replace()`**:

```
$value = preg_replace('/(.+).com\/(.*)/','$2', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```